# NodeJS application continues only 6 opened connections

Tags: node.js, http, tcp, server

I run a NodeJS application on Debian system, but last time I got in trouble with it.

I use http.createServer to run it and it seems that it supports only 6 opened connections at one time. That means if I poll the requests for 10 seconds, new have to wait these 10 seconds until previous are closed so they can get in.

I've completly ran out of ideas why it happens and I have no idea if its cause of the OS settings or applications, so I would really appreciate any advices.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are making an HTTP request from your browser then the browser can only make 6 concurrent requests. Did you return a response for each request? If you didn't then it each request would wait till it times out.

Comment: @RajanSharma Im not running the HTTP from the browser. The problem is literally the back end.

I wait with returning response for each request and thats a thing I cant get without doing. Ive described them as "opened" connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to increase the number of connections that your application should handle at a time then use the `POSIX` module to raise the limit on the number of file descriptors your process can use.

Install `posix`

```
npm install posix
```

Then in your code which runs the server

```
var posix = require('posix');
```

```
// raise maximum number of open file descriptors to 1k,
posix.setrlimit('nofile', { soft: 1000 });

// Note: The hard limit is unchanged after this, it updates the soft limit only.
```